# Prove/disprove that if $L_1, L_2\in RE$ then $L_1-\ L_2, L_1 - \bar{L_2}\in RE$

Tags: turing-machines

I need to prove\disprove that if $L_1, L_2\in RE$ then $L_1-\ L_2, L_1 - \bar{L_2}\in RE$.

Trying to prove those statements I thought about using the turing machines $M_1, M_2$ of $L_1, L_2$ respectively, but I can't simulate input on $M_1$ and $M_2$ since they might run forever.

How can I prove (or disprove) those two statements?

Answer (score 0):

For the statement which is false, you take your easiest example of a non-r.e. language (ie the complement of the Halting problem), and then show how it is expressible in the respective form.

For the statement which is true, you take semidecision procedures for $L_1$, $L_2$ and built one for the relevant language. If you do this properly, then the forever-running is not an issue. Or, if available to you, you invoke the closure of $\mathrm{RE}$ under intersection.

Comment: @RickDecker Almost, I wrote "true" instead of "false".

Answer (score 0):

We are given $L_1, L_2$ that belong to $RE$, hence there are TMs $M_1, M_2$ that *recognize* the languages (not decide). To check for $x \in L_1 - L_2$ we need to recognize $x \in L_1$ and $x \notin L_2$. But due to the nature of $RE$ languages, the machine to recognize $x \notin L_2$ may run forever.

Looking at your second problem, we have to recognize $x \notin \bar L_2$, which is same as $x \in L_2$. For a language in $RE$ this is doable. The language $L_1 - \bar L_2$ is the set of strings that belong to $L_1$ but do not belong to $\bar L_2$. The second condition can be written as strings that belong to $L_2$. Using the closure property of $RE$ under intersection you can complete your answer.